# Flutter Firestore: :How I can order firestore query by field/value inside map?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, sql-order-by

I tried:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('messages')                  
        .orderBy('sentDate', descending: false)
        .snapshots(),
```

but it didn't work.

[image: Firebase Firestore collection/path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order by the `sendDate` of a specific entry in the map you can using dot notation:

```
.orderBy('167361790.sentDate', descending: false)
```

---

If you want to sort on the `sentDate` of a dynamically selected map entry, that isn't possible with your current data model, and you'll want to modify your data model to allow the use-case.

For example, if you want to order the messages on the most recent `sentDate`, you should add a top-level field to the document `latestSentDate`, update that whenever you write to the map, and then sort on that.